# How to lay out content when the workflow for creating and consuming them is different?

Tags: input-fields, workflow, title

I'm doing a site that makes people write "cards" quickly. Each card contains of a title and a body.

However, the designed workflow is that the user:

1. Writes the body, listing out the detailed events
2. Quickly adds a title

With the situation, the user isn't trying to carefully plan out each step; the user needs to quickly spill out their thoughts (think brainstorming-esque) and then add a title so they can quickly scan through the information and see what each card is about.

It would make sense to have this layout:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3YRep.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

However, that seems confusing for the user to have content shift places when saved.

Even with different arrangements (read: side by side), the problem still persists: you expect to read the title first when viewing and expect to write the title last when creating. Furthermore, will a user want the title on the top when going back with modifications later (thus creating another discrepancy in the layout)?

I could still have the title last and have it bigger than the body text, but that breaks standard convention and makes the reader's eyes go up and down too much, especially when skimming through lots of information.

What's the best approach for this?

Comment: Can't you just keep the title on top but set the focus on the text box instead if that's where you expect them to start typing?

Comment: @illuminaut the issue is that the "tab flow" will be broken as it's somewhat unnatural to have it go up when you hit tab

Comment: Give users to option to customize it according to their needs?

Comment: @MichaelLai customization is always good, but it's often better to get it right the first time. Plus, why would every single user have a solution to this issue that none of us have?

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin as long as you don't fall into the trap of trying to create one solution for two different problems.

Comment: Is it a title, or is it a memorable name or a tag (or even bunch of different tags)? In other words, what role exactly will the title play in sharing, organising, remembering and refinding notes? Without this information, there's nothing we can tell about how the 'title' should be presented.

Comment: @SteveDL it's not a tag, but the exact usage may vary by the user. It's purpose is to create a "summary" for that "card" so it can be skimmed when there's 20 or 30 cards on your screen. It's usage is to, a bit later, allow the user to skim through all of the cards to "pick up where they left off" or another user to quickly get the main ideas of the brainstorming session. If they want more details or they don't understand the title, *then* they can look at the body.

Comment: What you need may very well depend on use contexts then. I'd imagine a team doing a team brainstorming/meeting session will want to create different categories of notes that they log into their team dashboard (maybe similar to Trello), whilst I as an academic would brush up project ideas, notes on paper reviews and TODO lists a bit like I'd use Google Keep. In the first case, the architecture and temporal relationship between the notes matters, but not in the second one. You have an information architecture problem here, not a UI problem.

Comment: @SteveDL I'm not asking how to make both views flow the same way; I'm saying, yes, this is what is inevitable because of the nature of the application, but what can I do to ease this problem? How should I lay everything out so it is easy to use? Do I sacrifice the consistency or do I make the flow of the application skewed when viewing?

Comment: Easy to use for *whom* in *what context*? This being said, there does not need to be consistency between the UIs of different tasks... The question is whether the UIs you have designed correspond to your users' tasks or not, not whether they are consistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the main goal you're trying to achieve is to streamline the content creation process.

A possible solution is to split the content creation process to two mini-steps:

1. First just offering a text box to spill out thoughts, encouraging users to invest in writing (because the required investment is low)

[image]

2. Second, after the user commits (saving the card) ask her to add a title. I illustrated two options.

[image]

The upside is that you're lowering the investment barrier required from the user to start creating content, at the expense of making the entire process longer (by adding a "speed bump" in the form of a second "title" mini-step).

The best solution would be, of course, to rid the user of the need to manually add a title. Have you considered asking the user to add tags? Perhaps you're over evaluating the value of titles altogether.

Regardless of the chosen solution, try and measure. Let the data lead you to the best solution (the one where the user's abandonment rate is lowest).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

A title is always expected on top. You could do something similar to Evernote. Title is inline and optional. If a user doesn't provide it, it is given a default title  - *Unitiled 1* Either way, the user can go back later and add the title.

[image]